# Why are my bootstrap-sass rules overriden by the user agent rules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with the 'bootstrap-sass' gem but for some reason, the behavior is absolutely not right.

Judging by a submit button styled with `class="btn"` like so

```
<div class="actions btn">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

The result is that there are the bootstrap styles, but they are overriden by the user-agent rules so that the result is the standard Chrome button that appears on top of the bootstrap one... Here is a link to what I get :

*http://hpics.li/9ddcb61

Also, without changing anything (all I did was try the suggestion in comments and put it back as it was), now things don't float around but are all vertical :

*http://hpics.li/f7605d0

This is what I get in Dev Tools :

*http://hpics.li/db602b0

This is the gem file

```
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'bootstrap-sass'

 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

I have a custom.css.scss file with this inside :

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "_bootstrap-responsive.scss";
```

I also have tried adding this to the application.css.scss before the require_self and require_tree with no success

```
*= require _bootstrap
*= require _bootstrap-responsive
```

This is the js file in case it would be useful

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

I have really no idea what is going on, moreover I did the railstutorial book and everything worked fine when I was on it, but on my own app, nothing works... :(

I'm not sure I gave all information but feel free to request!

Comment: you can maybe upload the picture somewhere and post the link. Try import "bootstrap-responsive"; instead of import "_bootstrap-responsive.scss";

Comment: I get a Sprockets::FileNotFound when replacing the import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you're telling it, namely creating a "Bootstrap-styled" button and placing a non-Bootstrap-styled submit button inside it.

Try simply adding the `btn` class to your submit button:

```
<%= f.submit , :class => "btn" %>
```

Comment: Thank you this was it, I guess the rest is also to my noobiness to bootstrap

Comment: @GeoffreyHug Well then we're both noobs: that was the first line of code for Rails I've ever written. ;)

Comment: Aha, and you solve my problem like that! Bootstrap is really great btw, in just one day I've been able to do so much.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap buttons and button styling requires the javascript part of bootstrap to be load also. You can do this by adding this line:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file above the line

```
//= require_tree
```

Comment: Unfortunately this line is already present in my application.js file, I'll add the content of the file to the post.